# aria-expanded returns undefined

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to work with toggling and having some issues with it returning it's value, here is my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var x = $('#tab-battle').attr('aria-expanded');
    var y = $('#tab-tradeskills').attr('aria-expanded');
    console.log($('#tab-tradeskills').attr('aria-expanded'));
    if (x == 'true'){
        $('#battle-wrapper').css('display', '');
    } 
    else{
        $('#battle-wrapper').css('display', 'none');
    }
    if (y == 'true'){
        $('#tradeskill-wrapper').css('display', '');
    }
    else{
        $('#tradeskill-wrapper').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-battle active"><a id="tab-battle" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Battle</a></li>
    <li class="tab-tradeskills"><a id="tab-tradeskills" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Trade Skills</a></li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: Forgot to say: it is returning as undefined.

```js
var x = $('#tab-battle').attr('aria-expanded');
var y = $('#tab-tradeskills').attr('aria-expanded');
console.log($('#tab-tradeskills').attr('aria-expanded'));
if (x == 'true'){
 $('#battle-wrapper').css('display', '');
}
else{
 $('#battle-wrapper').css('display', 'none');
}
if (y == 'true'){
 $('#tradeskill-wrapper').css('display', '');
}
else{
 $('#tradeskill-wrapper').css('display', 'none');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab-battle active"><a id="tab-battle" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Battle</a></li>
  <li class="tab-tradeskills"><a id="tab-tradeskills" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Trade Skills</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my full HTML this is my main html file, which includes serveral different HTML files:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title># - KoG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/game/default.css">
    <script src="../components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/game.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <ul class="navbar navbar-nav">
            <li><button id="btn-actions">Actions</button></li>
            <li><button id="btn-profile">Profile</button></li>
            <li><button id="btn-kingdom">Kingdom</button></li>
            <li><button id="btn-inventory">Inventory</button></li>
            <li><button id="btn-alliance">Alliance</button></li>
            <li><button id="btn-mail">Mail Box</button></li>
            <li><button onclick="location.href='user/logout'" type="button">Logout</button></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
            <!-- Include Side Bar Left -->
            <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#sidebar').load('sidebar_left.ejs');
            });
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="game">
            <div class="quest-bar">
                <p>Quest ###<p>
            </div>
            <div class="action-timer">
                Action Timer Place Holder
            </div>
            <div class="game-content" id="game-content">
            <!-- Import views -->
                <script>
                $(function(){
                    $('#game-content').load('actions.ejs');
                });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="kingdom" id="kingdom">
            <!-- Include Side Bar Right    -->
            <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#kingdom').load('sidebar_right.ejs');
            });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="statistics" id="stats-button statistics-h4">
        <div class="statistic-row" id='statistic-row'>
            <!-- Include Statistics -->
            <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#statistic-row').load('statistics.ejs');
            });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="../components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My guess is, it is trying to read the id before the file gets included.
EDIT: Okay so this is NOT the issue, for some reason it won't return any values for any attributes for any id, and I'm not exactly sure why.

EDIT:
Okay, so I've come to the conclusion that it is because I am including these html files. What I don't understand is why. I guess the jQuery loads before it can read the ID of the included elements from said file. I'd rather not have to make a jQuery file for every included HTML file just to combat this. I'm not even sure that would work either.

Comment: what is happening with what you have now? is there an error in console log?

Comment: It's returning undefined

Comment: added the demo of your code which is returning false

Comment: Okay a question then. I'm including this in a main html file that has the script included. Do I need to include it in this as well? Which seems wrong. But it isn;t working at all for me.

Comment: then something else is causing the problem and we dont know what it is so we cant figure out a solution for the problem

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what could be wrong. maybe it is trying to pull the id before the included document is loaded, in which case it wouldn't exist?

Comment: I added my main HTML file, I think my guess is right, I just don;t know how to combat it, really. Maybe putting my game.js script link on the bottom... nope that didn't work.

Comment: did you check console for error?

Comment: No error on server console, only error i get on browser console is undefined

Comment: Have you inspected the HTML in dev tools? Bootstrap *might* be screwing with the attribute.

Comment: It's not. I did a `.load('file', function(){});` and caught the variables that way, unfortunately when it is done loading it won;t do anything else. So I am convinced that it is me including the files, and it tries to read them before everything is loaded correctly.

Comment: Well, I have a pseudo-fix. I just wrote the script inside the included file and it works fine. Which is not ideal, but I guess I will use this method until I find a better one.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out, I had to use the load and pass in the function with it, as well.

```
    $('#game-content').load('actions.ejs', function(){
      $('#tab-battle').click(function(){
        var x = $('#tab-battle').attr('aria-expanded');
        if (x != 'true') {
          $('#battle-wrapper').show();
          $('#tradeskill-wrapper').hide();
        }
      });

      $('#tab-tradeskills').click(function(){
        var y = $('#tab-tradeskills').attr('aria-expanded');
        if (y == 'false') {
          console.log(y);
          $('#battle-wrapper').hide();
          $('#tradeskill-wrapper').show();
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```